# How to keep links inside a div container on the same line when window is resized

Tags: html, css

When resizing the window, i'd like to keep the 4 links there on the same line, and just shrink when wndow is resized instead of overlapping each other or moving to next line. How do I do that? I tried using inline block but didn't help. thw replies and reply are floated left and right respectively and the middle two links have margin right spacing and are relative position.

[image: Squished]

[image: Want like this on same line same spacing when resized]

HTML:

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="comment__item">
        <div class="infos"><img src="../uploads/profile_pic-1517251850125.png"></div>
        <div class="content" id="5a7334dd43ce600d48720884">
            <h3 class="comment__authorname">lilly</h3><br><b class="comment__time">6 days ago</b><br>
            <p>luv me</p><br><a id="reply1" href="#" onclick="reply1(this)">1 Replies</a><a href="#" class="flatbanstart">Ban</a><a href="#" id="deletecom" onclick="deletecom(this)">Delete</a><a href="#" id="reply2" onclick="reply2(this)">Reply</a>
            <form
                class="flatbanform" style="display: none;"><input name="untildate" class="flatpickr flatpickr-input" type="hidden" placeholder="Ban until..." value="2018-02-07 11:58"><input class="flatpickr flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="Ban until..." type="text" readonly="readonly">
                <input
                    name="reason" type="text" placeholder="Reason..."><input class="comidban" name="comid" type="hidden"><input class="adminidban" name="admin" type="hidden"><button type="button" class="flatban" onclick="banuser.bind($(this))()">Ban Now</button></form>
                    <div id="ebolaf"></div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="comment__item">
        <div class="infos"><img src="../uploads/profile_pic-1512409436797.jpg"></div>
        <div class="content" id="5a74ce6c4d31642adcc11782">
            <h3 class="comment__authorname">aizen</h3><br><b class="comment__time">5 days ago</b><br>
            <p>gg</p><br><a id="reply1" href="#" onclick="reply1(this)">0 Replies</a><a href="#" class="flatbanstart">Ban</a><a href="#" id="deletecom" onclick="deletecom(this)">Delete</a><a href="#" id="reply2" onclick="reply2(this)">Reply</a>
            <form class="flatbanform"
                style="display: none;"><input name="untildate" class="flatpickr flatpickr-input" type="hidden" placeholder="Ban until..." value="2018-02-07 11:58"><input class="flatpickr flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="Ban until..." type="text" readonly="readonly">
                <input
                    name="reason" type="text" placeholder="Reason..."><input class="comidban" name="comid" type="hidden"><input class="adminidban" name="admin" type="hidden"><button type="button" class="flatban" onclick="banuser.bind($(this))()">Ban Now</button></form>
            <div id="ebolaf"></div>
        </div>
    </div><br></div>
```

CSS:

```
#reply1{
  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  color:black;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#reply2{

  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  float:right;
  color:black;
  white-space:nowrap;

}

#deletecom{

  text-decoration: none;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:20px;
  color:red;
  white-space:nowrap;


}

.flatbanstart{

  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: auto;
  position:relative;
  margin-right:20px;
  color:red;
  white-space:nowrap;
}


.content {


  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;


  border-width: 1px 4px 4px 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c8c7b4;
  background-color: #ece5bd;

  /*background-image: -linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 18px, #dbada9 0, #dbada9 20px, transparent 19px),
                    -linear-gradient(#e1dab0 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 11px, #dbada9 0, #dbada9 14px, transparent 12px),
                    -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1dab0 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 11px, #dbada9 0, #dbada9 13px, transparent 12px),
                    -moz-linear-gradient(#e1dab0 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);

  */
  background-size: 100% 10px;
  color: #333;
  width: 73%;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;

}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when there isn't enough space? Horizontal scrolling?

Comment: no scolling. just shrink accodingly or at least hide it as it closes in

Comment: just dont want user to see everything overlapped and flowing into other lines

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the text to shrink when the display size reaches a point where the text would be too large to fit on one line.

To achieve this I would use [viewport percentage units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) as the font size in a media query. In the arbitrary example below I've defined minimum viewport width of 200px, anything smaller and the text will shrink.

Obviously you're going to have to play around with what exact sizes you want to use based on your design.

[Resizeable JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/piyoror/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">One</a> | 
    <a href="#">Two</a> | 
    <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    background: #D0D0D0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 200px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 8vw;
    }
}
```